# Clipping using multiple polygons from same layer in ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip, arcgis-10.4

I have a polygone shapefile and now I want to select a couple of polygons which are islands in one big polygon and clip that big polygon with these selected islands. I know that I can use ERASE tool but that is not a good solution because I must to export features in separate layers and after that to paste it back. So,  I need some tool (clipper) which allow me to select more than one splitting polygons. I want it in ArcGIS 10.4,  but if someone know solution in qgis that is acceptable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the "island" polygons that you want to use to clip the big polygons.

Use the Clip tool in QGIS, with the following settings:

- Input layer: Polygon shapefile
- Overlay layer: Polygon shapefile, *Selected Features only*